# Different UICollectionViewCells having the same address

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I need help making each cell adddress unique. When i change the background colour of cell 1, cell 4's background colour also changes. after checking the cell description i found that my cells are using the same 3 address. cell 1 address the same as cell 4, 7, 10..., cell 2 address is the same as cell 5, 8, 11... and cell 3 is the same as cell 6, 9, 12...

[image]

I want each cell to be unique but i want to reuse the same cell type for each cell.

my collectionView protocal code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return noOfQuestions!
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellid, for: indexPath) as! QuestionCell

    cell.starPageLabel.text = String(indexPath.row + 1)

    cell.addImageButton.tag = indexPath.item
    cell.addImageButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleAddImage), for: .touchUpInside)

    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: collectionView.frame.height)
}

func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
    currentPage = Int(targetContentOffset.move().x / view.frame.width)
}

@objc func handleAddImage () {
    print("Current Page: \(currentPage!)")
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: IndexPath(row: currentPage!, section: 0)) as! QuestionCell
    print(cell.description)
    cell.questionTextField.backgroundColor = .red
}
```

Comment: What issue is the reuse causing you?

Comment: Can you please rephrase the _question_ with the problem that you are facing included in it as well .

Comment: There is no problem to solve here. This is what reusability means - reusing the same cell for another `indexPath`. Why do you even care about the addresses of these cells?